# tenant vs lodger meaning

Tags: ambiguity

What is the difference between `a tenant` and `a lodger`? Both words seem to mean the same, so when is one preferred over the other, or is it a case of different terms to name the same thing?

Comment: ***The five main differences between a lodger and a tenant:*** 
http://www.lodgerlandlord.co.uk/2010/03/09/the-five-main-differences-between-a-lodger-and-a-tenant/

Comment: The link provided by @Josh61 says it all.  Should we keep the question?

Comment: You can remove it if you want, thanks again for the link

Comment: In the US a "tenant" would exclusively occupy an entire apartment or rented home, while a "lodger" would occupy a room, with some shared space with the landlord, and possibly shared meals, etc.  (But note that "tenant" may be used to describe, eg, a farmer who rents land, or a business which occupies a rented building.  "Lodger", on the other hand, is exclusively used to describe someone occupying a dwelling.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You got a good answer for BrE. In my experience, *lodger* is rarely used in AmE (I have never heard it used, and rarely seen it in print.)  People renting a room in another's home are usually called *roomers* or *roommates*. People renting a hotel room, motel room, vacation cabin, condo, (or even a "lodge" e.g. a *ski lodge*) for a short vacation are usually called "guests".

Comment: My experience is that AmE can use the words the same way the British article cited above explains it. My wife's elderly aunt has lodgers in California, and calls them just that.

Comment: +1, Brian. In AmE "lodger" can certainly be used, and would be understood, too. For the most part. But in the U.S., "tenant" is the term normally used for someone who *rents* domestic accommodations on a, more or less, permanent basis.

Comment: Noted and agreed. I certainly didn't mean to say that _lodger_ is **never** used, or that is is **incorrect**; just that I never hear it.  Checking ngram viewer, I can't seem to get it to show both AmE and BrE on same graph though.  This one https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=lodger&year_start=1900&year_end=2010&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Clodger%3B%2Cc0 shows it gradually dwindling in AmE until c. 2000, then rising. I guess I haven't been paying attention _lately_!

Comment: My comment was meant to indicate full and unmitigated agreement, Brian. :-)

Comment: In AmE, **boarder** is often used for this sense of **lodger**; and **boarding house.** This type of living arrangement is much, much less common now, but my grandmother took in boarders. The Air BnB of the 1920s?

Comment: Thanks. But not quite Air BnB. Air BnB involves vacating your house while the boarder/lodger/guest occupies it, and I don 't think it usually involves them eating your food. So presumably they get Bed, but instead of breakfast get **air**.